# How do you prove that there exists a real number that is equal or less than all real numbers?

Tags: logic

There exists an element in the set of real numbers which is equal to or less than all elements in the set of real numbers.

How can I prove that this statement is true?

Comment: You don't because it is not true...

Comment: How do you ask a proper question on math.SE? (The comment sums everything up, thanks!)

Comment: I'm curious as to why you think it's true.  I feel like a bit of background might help.  Were you thinking of positive reals for example?

Comment: I thought my question was different from proving there is no smallest real number

Comment: Unless you're talking about the extended real number line (ℝ⁺), which is the union of ℝ and {-∞} and {∞}, your statement is false. No element in the set ℝ is ≤ all other elements.

Answer (score 4):

you can't. the statement is false because for any such $x$ you've $x-1<x$